# populate object from command line and check object state

Tags: oop

I populate an object based on the users input from the commandline.
The object needs to have a certain amount of data to proceed. My solution so far is nested if-statements to check if the object is ready. Like below example.
Maybe 3 if-statements aren't so bad(?) but what if that number of if-statements starts to increase? What are my alternatives here? Let's say that X, Y and Z are three completely different things. For example let's say that object.X is a list of integers and object.Y is a string and maybe Z is some sort of boolean to return true only if object.Y has a certain amount of values?
I'm not sure polymorhism will work in this case?

```
do
    {
        if (object.HasX)
        {
            if (object.HasY)
            {
                if (object.HasZ)
                {
                    //Object is ready to proceed.
                }
                else
                {
                   //Object is missing Z. Handle it...
                }
            }
            else
            {
               //Object is missing Y. Handle it...
            }
        }
        else
        {
           //Object is missing X. Handle it...
        }
} while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(line));
```

Comment: You might want to read about the "single layer of abstraction" principle. And beyond that: such cascades of if/else are a clear road into problems. You should think hard to find other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

For complex logic workflow, I have found, it's important for maintainability to decide which level of abstraction the logic should live in.

Will new logic/parsing rules have to be added regularly?

Unfortunately, there isn't a way to avoid having to do explicit conditionals, they have to live somewhere.

Some things that can help keep it clean could be:

- Main function is only responsible for converting command line arguments to native datatypes, then it pushes the logic down to an object builder class, This will keep main function stable and unchanged, except for adding flag descriptions, THis should keep the logic out of the domain, and centralized to the builder abstraction
- Main function is responsible for parsing and configuring the domain, this isolates all the messy conditionals in the main/parsing function and keeps the logic outside of the domain models
- Flatten the logic,  `if not object.hasX; return`, next step you know `has.X`, this will still have a list of conditionals but will be flatter
- Create a DSL declarative rule language (more apparent when flattening).  This could be a rule processor, where the logic lives, then the outer main function could define that states that are necessary to proceed